# How to subtract a html textbox from a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get my old number from at database, subtract that from my new number and show me the difference

```
// Find diff
function updateDue() {

    var kmnew1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("kmnew").value);
    var kmold1 = document.getElementById("kmold").innerHTML = <?php echo $km ?>;

    // to make sure that they are numbers
    if (!kmnew) { kmnew = 0; }
    if (!kmold) { kmold = 0; }

    var ansD = document.getElementById("kmtot");
    ansD.value = kmnew1 - kmold1;
} 

"the value for new is: " <span id="kmnew"></span><br>    
"the value for old is: " <span id="kmold"></span><br> 
"the value for tot is: " <span id="kmtot"></span><br>   


<input type="number" name="kjoring" id="kmnew" style="height:15px;width:50px" onchange="updateDue()"/>
```

When I enter the number 1 in the input field, it will show:

"the value for old is: " 300 (That is right)
The other two walues are not shown.

Comment: you have once `kmnew`, then `kmnew1`

Comment: a `<span>` doesn't have a value. You'd have to set innerHTML

Comment: then you have twice the id 'kmnew', and _never set_ the content of span kmnew

Comment: So I should remove the 1 from bouth kmold and kmnew? And how do I set a value to <span>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the corrected code. See my comments for explanations!

```
// Find diff
function updateDue() {
    var kmold1 = parseInt('<?php echo $km; ?>');
    var kmnew1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("kminput").value);
    var tot = kmnew1 - kmold1;

    document.getElementById("kmtot").innerHTML = tot;
    document.getElementById("kmnew").innerHTML = kmnew1;
    document.getElementById("kmold").innerHTML = kmold1;
}
```

HTML:

```
"the value for new is: " <span id="kmnew"></span><br>    
"the value for old is: " <span id="kmold"></span><br> 
"the value for tot is: " <span id="kmtot"></span><br>   


<input type="number" name="kjoring" value="" id="kminput" style="height:15px;width:50px" onchange="updateDue()"/>
```

Working snippet: https://jsbin.com/wesorepoka/edit?html,js,output

To make it easier you could already pass the new value from your input to the function:

```
<input type="number" name="kjoring" value="" id="kminput" onchange="updateDue(this.value)" style="height:15px;width:50px" />

// Find diff
function updateDue(kmnew) {   // here you get the passed value
    var kmold1 = parseInt('<?php echo $km; ?>');
    var kmnew1 = parseInt(kmnew); // only this line changed
    var tot = kmnew1 - kmold1;

    document.getElementById("kmtot").innerHTML = tot;
    document.getElementById("kmnew").innerHTML = kmnew1;
    document.getElementById("kmold").innerHTML = kmold1;
}
```

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You can also do `onchange="updateDue(this.value)"` to pass the value to the function directly. Then you don't need to fetching the DOM object and it's value in the function.

Comment: No worries. We're all here to help out :-)

Comment: Thank you for your great help, but how can i then tramsfere that value to post, so i can get it back to sql? @Jeff

Comment: what do you mean with "value to post"? 1st: which value (the total?)?

Comment: @jeff Like <form action="update.php" method="post">   <input type="hidden" name="kmtot" id="kmtot">  <input type="submit"  style="height:40px;width:350px" />